# Does there exist a theorem whose known proofs encapsulate all possible proofs of that theorem?

Tags: logic, soft-question

I was just reading a book on number theory which gave ten different proofs of the infinitude of the primes. This caused me to wonder whether or not it would be possible in principle to find every proof of the infinitude of primes which in turn caused me to wonder if there exists a theorem whose known proofs encapsulate all possible proofs of that theorem. If this question is complete nonsense please let me know.

Comment: A proof is a justification that some statement is true, and as such there isn't a really good way to count how many ways there is to prove something, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

If there is one proof, then there are infinitely many, since you can always add trivial steps. You see this really clear in formal proofs: once I have a statement $P$ I can always derive $P \lor Q$ for any of an infinite number of statements $Q$, before getting to the theorem.

Of course, one can complain that adding nonsense steps doesn't really change the 'core' of the proof, but making that kind of thing hard, i.e. trying to determine when one proof the really is 'different' from another becomes mostly a subjective exercise.

Comment: So is there no way to make this 'subjective exercise' more objective? Is trying to rigidly define one proof as different from another doomed to fail?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a subjective exercise. You could, for example, look for all the cut-free proofs in a sequent calculus equipped with proof terms, Or, to put it another way, all the normal forms of a given type. For example, in the polymorphic lambda calculus, corresponding to [second order propositional logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_propositional_logic), there are exactly two normal form terms of type $\forall P.P \to P \to P$ namely $\lambda xy.x$ and $\lambda xy.y$.

Comment: @Derek Elkins do have any book recommendations that would help me understand what you just wrote? I didn't understand the terms 'cut-free proofs,' 'sequent calculus,' 'proof terms,' 'normal forms,' or  'polymorphic lambda calculus.' My background is in philosophy but I'm only familiar with basic first order logic.

Comment: @Sid I actually intended that comment to be directed at Bram28, though it does serve as a response to your comment. The general area is [proof theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_theory) and specifically [structural proof theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_proof_theory) and even more specifically the [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus) and [natural deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction) both introduced by Gentzen. My approach to this has been through programming language theory.

Comment: I haven't read any books specifically on proof theory, but the Wikipedia articles reference many. These are connected (among other ways) to programming languages via the [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_isomorphism). I like Sørensen's and Urzyczyn's [Lectures on the Curry-Howard Isomorphism](http://disi.unitn.it/~bernardi/RSISE11/Papers/curry-howard.pdf), but it's probably not the best entry-point for you. The connection is touched on in most of the Wikipedia articles which are decent introductions.

Comment: @Sid A starting point might be learning how to normalize a proof in natural deduction.